# What permissions mask should be given with O_CREAT?

Tags: linux, unix, file-io, file-permissions

When creating a file with `open` and `O_CREAT`, a permissions mask must be given as the third argument to the function. On Windows, 0777 suffices, but on Linux or other Unix-like systems, presumably it's considered better to specify something more restrictive.

Assuming you're creating a simple text file (specifically the output of a source code indenting tool), what's the most appropriate value to specify?

Comment: there are a ton of articles regarding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only creating a simple text file that will be read from and written to by the indenting tool, then just specify `644` - readable and writable by owner, read-only by everyone else, and nobody can execute it.